# How do I globally increase font size in editor in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, accessibility

`Help->Find Action->Increase Font` increases the font size in just *one* editor.

I want to do that -- but  globally.

Simply choosing "Use Custom Font" like this...

[image]

... sets the font size in the project panel, not the editor.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The UI and editor fonts are independent settings. As you have stated, `Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance` allows you to customize the UI font. To set the default font size for editor windows, you must configure the option in `File > Settings > Editor > Font`:

[image]